# How to dynamically change tkinter button color in a loop?

Tags: tkinter

**
I need a button in my tkinter frame which would dynamically change color based on the condition in the for loop.  This code is creating button after last iteration. But I need to update the button color in every iteration. Can someone please help in this.
**

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x200+200+200")
btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="butn_3")
btn1.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.5)

for i in range(2,10):

        if i<5:
            btn1.config(background="green")
        if i>5:
            btn1.config(background="red")
mainloop()
```

Comment: You just need to change to green before the for loop, then change to red when i is 5 in the for loop.  To see the update immediately, call `btn1.update()` right after changing color.

Answer (score 0):

I have created code that changes the color every second, in a random order.

I hope this solves your problem.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
from random import shuffle
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x200+200+200")
btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="butn_3")
btn1.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.5)
root.update()
colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "black", "white", "cyan"]
while True:
   shuffle(colors)
   for i in range(0,len(colors)):
      btn1.config(background=colors[i])
      btn1.update()
      time.sleep(1)
root.mainloop()
```